# php make it say null

Tags: php

An example of where I have a variable and its value is "null".However, when I echo it out, it shows as nothing (because its null).

test.php:

```
<?php

$a=null;
echo 'start'.$a.'end';

?>
```

Is there a way to make this output 'startnullend' when the file test.php is requested in firefox?  var_dump does not work, nor does print_r for some reason.  The easy way is to IF test for null and then output null using if statement, but is there a different way?

Comment: If the answers present are not satisfactory, leave some feedback to that effect. Your question is not very clear, so if people misunderstand you, then clarify what you need

Comment: Most top answers have used an if statement, but the question was looking for a different way to do it.  Please close/delete the question.  Thanks.

Comment: So accept the answer that answers your question the closest (which is to say, "you can't without a conditional"). Being told there's no answer is still an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `var_dump` or `print_r` to show the value.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why this couldn't in the other question, but use this

```
<?php
   $a=null;
   echo 'a'.($a===null?'null':$a).'b';
?>
```

Comment: Since we're specifically talking `null`, you should use `===`.

Comment: I think `is_null` is more appropriate, since it's more *portable* (In common SQL dialects, `NULL == NULL` is false, so you need to use some kind of `IS NULL` operator).  While it's not strictly true in PHP, I still personally prefer to see `is_null` instead of an `===` comparison...

Answer (score 3):

Casting `null` to a string results in an empty string. If you want to output `null`, you will have to explicitly do:

```
echo 'start'.((is_null($a)) ? 'null' : '').'end';
```

Or something else similar.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
echo 'start'.(isset($a) ? $a : 'null').'end';
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a var_dump instead of an echo

```
var_dump($var)
```

Shows the type as well as the value

Answer (score 1):

you can use `var_dump` or `print_r`

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for that - var_dump();

or, try this function:

```
function getReadableVar($var){
if($var === null){
 $var = "null";
}elseif($var === true){
 $var = "true";
}elseif($var === false){
 $var = "false";
}
return $var;
}

echo getReadableVar($var);
//or
echo var_dump($var);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  // prints 'null', if $var is null
  echo is_null($var) ? 'null' : $var;
  // prints 'true' or 'false'
  echo (bool)$var ? 'true' : 'false'
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to a string first:

```
echo (string)$myvar;
```

Comment: This will result in an empty `""` string as well, since that's what `echo` is actually doing in the background...

Answer (score 0):

Make it a string?

```
$a = 'null';
```

Comment: Cannot change $a, its from an external source (had to include its definition to simplify the example).

Comment: Why would you want to print nothing?

Comment: need to put it into a mysql table.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to do it and invoke it when you want to check for null.

```
function n($var) {
    return $var === null ? "null" : $var;
}
```

And use it each time.

```
$a=null;
echo 'start'.n($a).'end';
```

Comment: `=== false`? That will fail when comparing to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show up on screen the string NULL then :

```
$a = "NULL";
```

otherwise null is a reserved word yeah?

Answer (score 0):

```
function toString($a) {
 return is_null($a) ? "null" : $a;
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: You got your values mixed up.  This will print `$a` if it's null, and `'null'` if it's not.

Comment: Nope, Rocket *was* right. I messed it up... But it's corrected now